# How do i run a script whenever i switch to a certain user?

Tags: bash, login

i've put the script i want to run in ~/.bash_login, but that doesn't work when i just switch to the user from another user.

Is there another such file ? something else?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you "switch to the user".  The `.bash_profile` file is used by the `bash` shell when it starts as a login shell, not otherwise.

Therefore, if you use `sudo`, you must make sure that you get a login shell when you switch users, by using its `-i` flag:

> `-i`, `--login`
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as `.profile` or `.login` will be
>                    read by the shell.  [...]

That means that

```
sudo -i -u otheruser
```

would probably work for you.

This assumes that `bash` is in fact the login shell specified in `/etc/passwd` for the user `otheruser`.

Answer (score 0):

Include the script in /home/username/.bashrc

Tested and worked fine

Below one is sample example

cat .bashrc

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
sh /tmp/l.sh =====>[ its a script which is going to execute when you logged in to this user]
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```